# Execute 2 for loops in Oracle SQL with cursors

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql, database-cursor

I am using a procedure to get data from a table called transactions. The table has 1000 rows and I have to read 50 records in a cursor once. And for each record, I need to print the output. Then the function should get the next 50 records from the table and do the same.

I am getting the logic, but the output isn't correct. Not both the for loops are working. Could you please find the code below and assist me with this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TWO_CURSOR IS
startC number := 1;
endc number := 3 ;
    cursor v_count is
    select (count(*) /50) from transactions;

    cursor transc  is
    SELECT transactions_id, product_id
    FROM transactions
    where rownum >= startC
    and rownum <= endc;
v_productName masterdata.product_name %TYPE;
v_supplierId masterdata.supplier_id %type;
v_supplierName masterdata.supplier_name %type;
v_price masterdata.price %type;
begin
for i in v_count
  LOOP
     for j in transc
     loop
       select product_name into v_productName from masterdata m where product_id=j.product_id;
       dbms_output.put_line( j.product_id || ' - ' || j.transactions_id || ' - ' ||  v_productName);
      end loop;
     startC := startC +3;
     endc := endc+3 ;

end loop;
END TWO_CURSOR;

> Blockquote

This is the output that I'm getting 

[output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2wGX.png
```

Comment: @barbaros Ozhan what did you edit? could you please let me know if you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said everything; I just coded it (the way I understood the question). Note lines #18 - 21.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure two_cursor is
  2    startc   integer := 1;
  3    endc     integer := startc + 49;
  4    endcount integer;
  5
  6    cursor transc  is
  7    select transactions_id, product_id
  8    from transactions
  9    where transactions_id between startc and endc
 10    order by transactions_id;
 11
 12    v_productname masterdata.product_name %type;
 13    v_supplierid masterdata.supplier_id %type;
 14    v_suppliername masterdata.supplier_name %type;
 15    v_price masterdata.price %type;
 16
 17  begin
 18    -- calculate endCount value
 19    select round(count(*) / 50)
 20      into endcount
 21      from masterdata;
 22
 23    for i in 1..endcount
 24    loop
 25    dbms_output.put_line( i );
 26       for j in transc
 27       loop
 28          select product_name into v_productname
 29          from masterdata
 30          where product_id = j.product_id;
 31          dbms_output.put_line( j.product_id || ' - ' || j.transactions_id
 32            || ' - ' ||  v_productname);
 33       end loop;
 34       startc := startc + 50;
 35       endc := endc + 50;
 36    end loop;
 37  end two_cursor;
 38  /
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This is really nice. I managed to find a way by creating another cursor.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TWO_CURSOR IS 
startc integer := 1;
endc integer := 50;

    cursor endCount is
    select transactions_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY transactions_id )
    from transactions
    where transactions_id <= (select (count(*)/50)-197 from transactions);  

begin

for i in endCount 
loop 
''' 

I have used this and this works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

None of the posted solutions actually produce what your descriptions specifies. Your initial attempt fails due to the predicate

```
where rownum >= startC
```

That works on the 1st iteration because the variable "startC" has a value of 1, but fails on all subsequent iteration because "startC" has been incremented. The psudo column rownum is not cumulative each execution of the Select initializes it to 1; it increments later when a row is selected. But to be selected the predicate "rownum >= startC" must be True. So the 1st row is not selected, and the rownum IS NOT incremented (it remains 1) so it fails for all subsequent rows. Result, NO rows are selected.  
The other 2 solutions "fail" as both depends upon the assumption that there are NO gaps in the transactions_id. While both work as long as that assumption holds, it is not a realistic realistic assumption, unless you have gone through considerable coding to keep then gap-less.  
As far as dynamically providing an endCount there are essentially 2 ways. Create a stored procedure and pass parameters, or create a anonymous and provide bound variables or substitution variables. Moreover, with either you can use a single cursor and bulk collect so as to not need a individual select for each transaction+product combination.

```
create or replace procedure product_list_by_n_elements(
          group_size  in integer default 50
        , max_groups  in integer default 20
        ) is

    cursor c_prod_trans  is
       select m.product_id
            , m.product_name
            , t.transactions_id           
         from masterdata   m
         join transactions t
           on t.product_id = m.product_id
        order by t.transactions_id, m.product_id; 

    type c_prod_trans_list_t is 
         table of c_prod_trans%rowtype;

    prod_trans_list  c_prod_trans_list_t; 

    processing_group integer := 0;
    first_entry      integer := 0;
    last_entry       integer := 0;    
begin
   open c_prod_trans;
   loop
       processing_group := processing_group + 1;      
       fetch c_prod_trans
             bulk collect
             into prod_trans_list
            limit group_size;

       first_entry := last_entry + 1;
       last_entry  := last_entry + prod_trans_list.count;

       dbms_output.put_line( 'Group: '     || to_number(processing_group)
                            || ' Entries:' || to_number(first_entry)
                            || ' - '       || to_number(last_entry )
                           );

       for prod_trans_entry in 1 .. prod_trans_list.count
       loop
           dbms_output.put_line(  '    ' || to_number(prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).product_id)
                                || ' - ' || to_number(prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).transactions_id) 
                                || ' - ' || prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).product_name 
                               );    
       end loop;

       exit when prod_trans_list.count < group_size 
              or processing_group >= max_groups;

   end loop;
end product_list_by_n_elements;
```

Or as a anonymous block with substitution parameters.

```
declare
    group_size  integer := &Group_Size;
    max_groups  integer := &endCount; 

    cursor c_prod_trans  is
       select m.product_id
            , m.product_name
            , t.transactions_id           
         from masterdata   m
         join transactions t
           on t.product_id = m.product_id
        order by t.transactions_id, m.product_id; 

    type c_prod_trans_list_t is 
         table of c_prod_trans%rowtype;

    prod_trans_list  c_prod_trans_list_t; 

    processing_group integer := 0;
    first_entry      integer := 0;
    last_entry       integer := 0;    
begin
   open c_prod_trans;
   loop
       processing_group := processing_group + 1;      
       fetch c_prod_trans
             bulk collect
             into prod_trans_list
            limit group_size;

       first_entry := last_entry + 1;
       last_entry  := last_entry + prod_trans_list.count;

       dbms_output.put_line( 'Group: '     || to_number(processing_group)
                            || ' Entries:' || to_number(first_entry)
                            || ' - '       || to_number(last_entry )
                           );

       for prod_trans_entry in 1 .. prod_trans_list.count
       loop
           dbms_output.put_line(  '    ' || to_number(prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).product_id)
                                || ' - ' || to_number(prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).transactions_id) 
                                || ' - ' || prod_trans_list(prod_trans_entry).product_name 
                               );    
       end loop;

       exit when prod_trans_list.count < group_size 
              or processing_group >= max_groups;

   end loop;
end;
```

**Disclaimer**. As you did not post test data neither routine has been tested, However they are syntactically valid.